# How to pass Guid values from Manager to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the manager code which through which I'm trying to pass data

```
public Response AddDocument(JDocument value)
{
    var response = new Response();
    try
    {
        string spName = "[dbo].[xxxxxxxxx]";
        this.Connect();
        this.ClearSPParams();
        this.AddSPStringParam("@Id1", value.Id1.ToString()); 
        this.AddSPStringParam("@Id2", value.Id2.ToString());
        this.AddSPStringParam("@DocumentType", value.DocumentType);
        this.AddSPStringParam("@DocumentName", value.DocumentName);
        this.AddSPStringParam("@Format", value.Format);
        this.AddSPStringParam("@Description", value.Description);
        this.AddSPStringParam("@Folder", value.Folder);
        this.AddSPStringParam("@DocumentPath", value.DocumentPath);
        this.AddSPFloatParam("@FileSizeInKB", value.FileSizeInKB);                        
        this.AddSPParamOut("@DocId", 50);
        this.AddSPReturnIntParam("@RetVal");
        this.ExecuteSelectSP(spName);
        var id = this.GetOutValueString("@DocId");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            value.Id = Guid.Parse(id);
        response.Code = this.GetOutValueInt("@RetVal");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.Utils.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

In my stored procedure it is:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxxxxxx]
 @Id1 uniqueidentifier,
 @Id2 uniqueidentifier,
 @DocumentType varchar(50)=null,
 @DocumentName varchar(100)=null,
 @Format varchar(50)=null,
 @DocumentPath varchar(256),
 @Description varchar(250)=null,
 @Folder varchar(30),
 @FileSizeInKB float=null,
 @DocId uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
```

This throws an error saying cannot convert varchar to unique identifier. Is there any alternative to AddSPStringParam so that I can directly pass Guid/uniqueidentifier and not as a string ?

Comment: What does `AddSPStringParam` look like?

Comment: Does `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier` not work?

Comment: yes i know spstringparam means I'm sending it as string hence it wont accept. what i'm asking is how to pass guid directly. using spparam only

Comment: why do people downvote without knowing anything ? I'm comfortable using this method only hence I asked if any workaround is there or not using SPParam itself. seriously. there should be report button for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AddSPStringParam` is adding parameters to the stored procedure as `varchar`. However, your stored procedure expects a `uniqueidentifier`.

You will have to create a new function that adds a parameter of the type `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier`.

Comment: we're working with SPParam itself. making a function will cost time which we can't give as of time being. previously I was doing with the same, just making guid in SP as varchar and clearing the stuff but now I want to do it properly thats why

Comment: any help with SPParam?